# Not able to get facebook user details using Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to intergrate facebook connect webtechnick plugin with my Cakephp application.
My login and logout is working, but i am not able to get the facebook user details like username, userid,firstname,lastname etc..

Here is my code in Appcontroller:

```
public $components = array(
            'Session','Facebook.Connect'=>array('model' => 'User'));

public function beforeFilter() {

$this->set('facebook_user', $this->Connect->user());

 }
```

when i tried this in my view `<?php echo debug($facebook_user);?>`
I am getting null value

How can i solve this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your user is logged out when your making the call to `$this->Connect->user()` which is calling `FB->api('/me')`. Depending on the debug level you set in the /Config/core.php & with the php.ini settings `html_errors = On`, you should get Exceptions thrown if this is the case & would explain why you get an empty response.

Personnally, I use in AppController.php :

```
public function beforeFilter(){
    if($this->Connect->FB->getUser() != 0){
        $this->set('facebookUser', $this->Connect->user());
    }
}
```

This way, it doesn't try to call the api if I do not have an access token that grants access to non-generic details (id, name, bio, etc.). Having a 0 for FB->getUser() answer meaning that the user didn't grant access to his data for this app, thus allowing no user_token to call `api(/me)`.

Anyway, you should try to debug the issue from inside the controller, try to add `var_dump($this->Connect->uid, $this->Connect->me);` at the end of beforeFilter() and see what you get.